# What design pattern best fits this multiple implementations per customer method?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have customers and each customer has a method to generate a reference number, but the reference number is different for each customer.  I have an implementation below, but I am curious if there are any scalability issues and what design pattern is this or what design pattern would best fit this scenario:

```
//All customers will implement this.
public interface ICustomer
{

}

//All customers will implement this.
public interface IReferenceNumber
{
    string GenerateReferenceNumber();
}

   public class CustomerOne : ICustomer, IReferenceNumber
{
    public string GenerateReferenceNumber()
    {
        return "Reference Implemenation 1";
    }
}

public class CustomerTwo : ICustomer, IReferenceNumber
{
    public string GenerateReferenceNumber()
    {
        return "Reference Implemenation 2";
    }
}
```

Here is how I might call it:

```
Dictionary<string,ICustomer> customers = new Dictionary<string,ICustomer>();

customers.Add("CustomerOne",new CustomerOne());
customers.Add("CustomerTwo",new CustomerTwo());

CustomerOne customerOne = (CustomerOne)customers["CustomerOne"];
CustomerTwo customerTwo = (CustomerTwo)customers["CustomerTwo"];

Console.WriteLine(customerOne.GenerateReferenceNumber());
Console.WriteLine(customerTwo.GenerateReferenceNumber());
```

Here are some more specific questions:

1. The only reason why I had ICustomer was so I didn't have to do something like `Dictionary<string,object> customers = new Dictionary<string,object>()`, but now I am wondering if the `IReferenceNumber` is unnecessary and `GenerateReferenceNumber` should be moved into `ICustomer`

Also, I hate having to do `CustomerOne customerOne = (CustomerOne)customers["CustomerOne"];`.  Is there a way I can just get the Customer back and call the method on it without having to explicitly cast?

It seems based on comments, I should just have something like:

```
public class Customer
{
   public string GenerateReferenceNumber()
   {
       //Logic
       return "Default reference number";
   }
}
```

But if each customer requires unique logic to generate a reference number, how can I only keep one Customer object and override the behavior unless I have multiple `GenerateReferenceNumber` methods or `one huge if else statement` or `different concrete implementations of customers` that can use the default reference number or their own unique logic to generate one.

Comment: It may just be the wording of your classes, but it sounds like there should only be one `Customer` class with a `ReferenceNumber` property, and then you instantiate that class to get `customer1`, `customer2`, etc

Comment: Have I missed something, Why are you creating a class per customer? If you have 100 customers are you really going to write 100 classes?

Comment: @jbabey - What if each customer has a different implementation of GetReferenceNumber?

Comment: Seems to me a bit like [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). And I agree strongly with @jbabey in that you really should have only one `Customer` class.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko - That is what I am trying to avoid, hence, one of the reason why I asked the question.  I thought I needed to create multiple concrete customers if they implement GetReferenceNumber differently.

Comment: "What if each customer has a different implementation of GetReferenceNumber?" - o_O different *how*? Usually you'd have *one and only one* algorithm to get what you want. Feed that algorithm with one, three or sixteen parameters to change the outcome if you like, but don't create a different algorithm for each customer.

Comment: @Corak - I used a simple example here.  If one customer requires unique logic to GenerateReferenceNumber and another requires different logic, if I had one method, wouldn't that require a lot `if else if customer`

Comment: You only need one `Customer` class. You don't need a different implementation for each individual `Customer`. They can use the same algorithm to generate different reference numbers. If you do find a need to implement additional algorithms, you could look into the strategy design pattern.

Comment: I will update my post.

Comment: I think the big thing that is confusing people is the fact you named your class `Customer` if it was `ICustomerType` for the interface and your classes where something like public class `SmallBuisnessCustomer: ICustomerType` and `LargeBuisnessCustomer: ICustomerType` the logic would make more sense.

Comment: Okay, I'd probably use an enum of all known algorithms and have one big switch statement to call the right one for a specific enum value. But if that doesn't work for you, again I refer you to [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). The one Customer class has a property of type `IReferenceNumberGetter`. All the different algorithms are implemented by seperate classes who implement `IReferenceNumberGetter` and when you instantiate a Customer you provide him with the right one.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - I think you are right. Customer was too generic. These are very different when I mentioned CustomerOne and CustomerTwo. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Corak - Can you provide an answer with your example.

Comment: @Corak - So you are saying to have multiple classes that each implement GenerateReferenceNumber instead of multiple Customers, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the GenerateReferenceNumber() method to ICustomer interface and use it in dictionary much simpler:

```
//All customers will implement this.
public interface ICustomer
{
    string GenerateReferenceNumber();
}

public class CustomerOne : ICustomer
{
    public string GenerateReferenceNumber()
    {
        return "Reference Implemenation 1";
    }
}

public class CustomerTwo : ICustomer
{
    public string GenerateReferenceNumber()
    {
        return "Reference Implemenation 2";
    }
} 


Dictionary<string,ICustomer> customers = new Dictionary<string,ICustomer>();

customers.Add("CustomerOne",new CustomerOne());
customers.Add("CustomerTwo",new CustomerTwo());

var customerOne = customers["CustomerOne"];
var customerTwo = customers["CustomerTwo"];

Console.WriteLine(customerOne.GenerateReferenceNumber());
Console.WriteLine(customerTwo.GenerateReferenceNumber());
```

Or if you really want to keep both interfaces you can make the ICustomer derived from IReferenceNumber:

```
public interface ICustomer : IReferenceNUmber
{

}
```

and then the usage is the same - no cast required.

As for design pattern question, I don't see any specific design pattern that should be used here. It is basic case of inheritance, not the more complex behavior which has design pattern to implement it as a general approach. So no need for complicating this code with design patterns.

Comment: Great, I removed IReferenceNumber and moved GenerateReferenceNumber into ICustomer.  Some comments above have indicated why I need to have multiple customers, but if each customer has different logic for generating a reference number, don't I need to have multiple classes?

Comment: If you have different logic for generating reference numbers, you need to have multiple classes. But if it's simply inirialization/return like in example, you should leave one class with reference number as a field/property.

Comment: Also if you have common logic, consider using abstract base class instead/in addition to the ICustomer interface. It will allow you to override just the methods you need or force every derived class to implement this method in it's own way

Comment: I just gave a simple example, but the logic to generate a reference number is much greater than this, I just wanted to point out that GenerateReferenceNumber would result in different values for different customers and the logic to get that would be different. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so based on your comment on using an abstract class and correct me if I am wrong, you are saying that if I have default implementation, it is best to use an abstract class because that way when a concrete object implements my abstract class, they would not be required to implement every method as if I used an interface, correct?

Comment: Actually not. I recommended abstract class for the case you have logic that use GenerateReferenceNumber method (it should be abstract method in this case) or you don't have default implementation and need to force anybody who derive from your class to provide his own implementation of GenerateReferenceNumber() for that specific class. If you have default implementation, you then must do this method virtual instead. Also all common logic other than GenerateReferenceNumber should also be implemented in base class for code reuse.

Comment: Also you can use non-abstract base class in case it logically contains all common logic and can be instantiated directly. Though in your case I doubt if this is the case - more likely you shouldn't have base class that can be instantiated. So I suppose abstract base class (with abstract method GenerateReferenceNumber) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), I'd come up with something like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    private readonly IReferenceNumberGetter ReferenceNumberGetter;

    public Customer(IReferenceNumberGetter referenceNumberGetter)
    {
        ReferenceNumberGetter = referenceNumberGetter;
    }

    public string GenerateReferenceNumber()
    {
        return ReferenceNumberGetter.GenerateReferenceNumber();
    }

    // other Customer stuff
}

public interface IReferenceNumberGetter
{
    string GenerateReferenceNumber();
}

public class ReferenceNumberGetterOne : IReferenceNumberGetter
{
    public string GenerateReferenceNumber()
    {
        return "4";
    }
}

public class ReferenceNumberGetterTwo : IReferenceNumberGetter
{
    public string GenerateReferenceNumber()
    {
        return "42";
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var customerOne = new Customer(new ReferenceNumberGetterOne()); 
var customerTwo = new Customer(new ReferenceNumberGetterTwo());
```

Comment: What benefit does this provide over having multiple customers override GenerateReferenceNumber as opposed to having multiple classes have different implements of GenerateReferenceNumber?

Comment: This way you only have *one* Customer class (I assume that class is bigger and the rest of it is independent of how the ReferenceNumber is generated). And only the part that is different is in different classes. If your `Customer` classes are really only(!) responsible for generating ReferenceNumbers then they would take the place of the different `ReferenceNumberGetter`.